# I need to convert an audio from .mp3 to .gsm

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, terminal, data-conversion, file-conversion

I need to convert from .mp3 to .gsm (preferably with ffmpeg).
I used it for several different formats but with this isn't as simple as it was with the others.
I don't know what parameters I'm missing.

I tried using ffmpeg with the following comand:

`ffmpeg -i ".\example.mp3" ".\example.gsm"`

But it shows me the following error:

`Sample rate 8000Hz required for GSM, got 44100Hz                                                           Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height   Conversion failed!`

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -ar 8000 -ac 1 -i ".\example.mp3" ".\example.gsm"
```

-ar sample rate
-ac audio channel

Comment: It didn't work. It shows

`Option sample_rate not found`

Comment: Could be your ffmpeg issue. Try on some other machine.